# Using r to compare two data of two versions of a file in git

Tags: r, git

I building a data set that I want to keep under version control. As a part of the release process I want to compare different version of the data set. For simplicity I want to keep the data in csv format.

How can I use R go fetch two different git versions of a data file? (Next step is to compare the content but that is not a part of the question)

Sample code: (Edit 2017-11-19 fixed some errors)

```
#
# re-using git2r sample code for status
#

## Create a temporary git repository
path <- tempfile(pattern="git2r-")
dir.create(path)
repo <- init(path)
setwd(path)

#
# set up a simple frame and commit it twice 
#

df <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:2)
write.csv2(df, "df.csv", row.names = FALSE)
add(repo, "df.csv")
commit(repo, "First commit message")
df <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:3)
write.csv2(df, "df.csv", row.names = FALSE)
add(repo, "df.csv")
commit(repo, "2nd commit message")
```

what I am looking for - a way to restore specific versions of the file

```
df_first_commit <- 
df_2nd_commit <-
```

and using the help from the accepted answer

```
checkout(commits(repo)[[1]])
df_2nd_commit <- read.csv2("df.csv")
checkout(commits(repo)[[2]])
df_first_commit <- read.csv2("df.csv")
```

Comment: I spent about 15 minutes reading through the `git2r` documentation, and I found nothing which would seem to help here.  If you want to checkout a certain file at a certain commit, then the command line way of doing this is `git checkout <SHA-1 hash> -- path/to/file.ext`.  You might have to use the command line here.

Comment: furthermore, if you want to compare different versions of the data set it might make more sense to do it via git, i.e. `git diff <ref1> <ref2>` ? If you know how to do something on the command line you can always use `system()` to execute the command from within R ...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - command line is definitely my fallback plan. My hope is that there is a way of avoiding this to reduce the complexity of my build chain. Thanks for your help

Comment: @BenBolker - Agree - cvs diff is a part of how I will work in keeping track of changes, but I would like quantify the differences using R. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one way to do this, maybe there's a better way.
It will involve `checkout` of different revisions,
and to do that safely it's important to start from a clean state,
with no uncommitted edits.

First, you need to find the commit you would like to switch to, inspect the result of:

```
commits(repo)
```

Once you know the commit you're interested in, switch to it:

```
# n is the commit number to switch to, 1 is the last, 2 is the one before, ...
checkout(commits(repo)[[n]])
```

At this point, you can read the file into `df_foo`.
You can switch to another commit to read into `df_bar` to make comparisons.
To switch back to your previous state:

```
checkout(repo, branch="master")
```

Based on `?checkout`,
I expected to be able to checkout a specific file at a given revision,
but this didn't work for me:

```
# doesn't work
checkout(commit, path="df.csv")
```

It seems that checkout of a specific file only works with a `repo` parameter, and doesn't work with a specific commit.
For example this works to replace the content of a specific file from the index:

```
checkout(repo, path="df.csv")
```

More importantly, I was looking for the equivalent of `git show SHA:path`,
to get the content of a file, but the documentation of the `show` method is useless, and my feeble attempts were not fruitful:

```
# nothing useful here
show(commit, ":df.csv")
show(paste0(commit@sha, ":df.csv"))
```

Comment: This solution works fine with me. Wrapped up the final steps in the questions. Feels good to hear, that I am not the only one confused by the doc in git2r.